# What did this captain mean by this?

Tags: dialogue, the-deuce

In an episode of the Deuce, patrolman Alston is asked to tour the precinct with his new captain. On the tour, the captain tells Alston that in the hopes of learning what really goes on on the streets, he was advised to seek out a black officer who hasn't risen through the ranks- because said officer likely has "got no rabbi" and therefore is "on the outside enough to be trusted."

Does anyone know what the captain meant when he said "got no rabbi?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Law Enforcement a "rabbi" is an older member of the force who will take a new recruit under his wing for mentoring and, if needed, protection.

policemag.com offers up some similar definitions

http://www.policemag.com/cop-slang/rabbi.aspx

RABBI

1.RABBI

A senior officer that acts as a mentor or a senior officer to go to for reliable and confidential advice.

2.RABBI

A superior in whom the policeman/woman can go to in confidence for advise, especially in dealing with in house problems and personal or family matters.

3.RABBI

A high ranking officer in a department who serves as mentor or a "hook" for a younger officer to get ahead in the department without really earning it.